# How to obtain Components Name from a bpl on my standalone app

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bpl

`Classes.GetPackageInfo` can enumerate all the units and required packages for a package. But I want a Proc like :

```
procedure GetPackageComponents(ModuleName: PChar; ComponentsList: TStrings);
```

which will obtain all IDE-Components from a Designtime package.
And is it possible be a general way?  eg. call this proc from a VC app ?

Comment: Something similar has been asked [`here`](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/71/506200.html), but it's quite old dated. Anyway could you include your Delphi version in you question (it might be important) ? Thanks!

Comment: Delphi 7.  And we can know runtime or designtime by GetPackageInfo, flags will tell you pfDesignOnly or pfRunOnly.

Comment: What do you mean by "IDE-Components", "general way" and "VC app"? Please edit your question to be more specific and clear.

Comment: to TOndrej. "IDE-Components"- IDE awareness components, eg. Delphi IDE can identify all components after you Install a pacakge from menu-"Component-Install Package-Add"; "getneral way"&"VC app(Visual C++)" means a way that doesn't depend on Borland-technology, or means a normal win32 method, this is just for curious

Comment: @explorer The Delphi IDE does not really "identify" components. It simply looks for a procedure with the name Register and if found in a Design time package calls it. The Register procedure then typically calls the RegisterComponents function. So its rather the package that tells the IDE about the components then the IDE identifying the components.